# Snowflake: Snowpark Python session not able to flatten the Json

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the error `ValueError: Incorrect number of arguments passed to the UDF: Expected: 0, Found: 1`.
I have tried `VariantType` as well for return type.

```py
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf

@udf(name='flatten_json', return_type=StringType(), is_permanent=False, replace=True, session=new_session)
def flatten_json(raw_response):
    return raw_response
data.select(flatten_json(F.col("raw_response"))).show()
```

I was expecting the column value to come up but got the error instead.

Comment: What is `F.col("raw_response")` returning?

Comment: the code above returns, ValueError: Incorrect number of arguments passed to the UDF:

F.col("raw_response") is a json column.